# Twitter: Authentication changed? App crashes suddenly on authentication window (Titanium)

Tags: iphone, authentication, twitter, crash, titanium

My twitter part on my app suddenly doesn't work anymore. When I want to authenticate the app crashes. I get a fast glimpse of the pop up window to login (Which has a new layout) and it crashes with the following errors:

> http://www.pastie.org/1846358

It worked fine yesterday, so I guess there's a problem with the new layout of the auth window or so? I can't really find something in the output what the problem was, beside that it gives errors about the html things.

Can anyone help me out? Or does anyone have the same problem, and confirm that I'm not the only one?

I'm using Titanium SDK 1.6.2 and iPhone SDK 4.2.

Thanks!

Comment: The problem is solved now, the authentication window changed back to the old one. Can anyone explain this behavior? It's quite annoying if that would happen again if the app gets published. I had a completely different pop-up screen to authorize your account for the app with twitter. After an hour it changed back to the normal one.

Comment: Have you tried asking around at Twitter support, they control the entire thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use MGTwitterEngine, go to SA_OAuthTwitterController.m. And change this:

```
- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad: (UIWebView *) webView {
NSError *error;
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"jQueryInject" ofType: @"txt"];
NSString *dataSource = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding       error:&error];

if (dataSource == nil) {
    //YFLog(@"An error occured while processing the jQueryInject file");
}

//DLog(@"%@", [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML"]);
[_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:dataSource]; //This line injects the jQuery to make it look better
//check for auth_pin element
NSString *authPin = [[_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.getElementById('oauth_pin').innerHTML"] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
authPin = [[_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.getElementById('oauth_pin').getElementsByTagName('kbd')[0].getElementsByTagName('code')[0].innerHTML"] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
if (authPin.length == 0)
    authPin = [[_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.getElementById('oauth_pin').getElementsByTagName('a')[0].innerHTML"] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
//if the auth pin not found than check for the auth-pin elenent
if (authPin == nil || authPin.length == 0) {
    authPin = [[_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.getElementById('oauth-pin').innerHTML"] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    if (authPin.length == 0) {
        authPin = [[_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: @"document.getElementById('oauth-pin').getElementsByTagName('a')[0].innerHTML"] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: [NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    }
}
[_activityIndicator stopAnimating];
if (authPin.length) {
    [self gotPin: authPin];
} 
if ([_webView isLoading] || authPin.length) {
    [_webView setHidden:YES];
} else {
    [_webView setHidden:NO];
}
}
```